# Why is Kirchoff's Voltage Rule not satisfied when the circuit is shorted?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, short-circuits

For example if I have a simple circuit with a battery and a resistor, and then the resistor is shorted, Kirchoff's Rule is no longer satisfied. Since the current through the resistor is 0, the voltage equation for that particular loop becomes V - I*R = 0 and I = 0.

Is Kirchoff's Rule incorrect for this scenario?

Comment: In case of a short circuit the voltage has to be zero, but there can still be a current flow and Kirchhoff's laws are still correct. In any case, this is more of a degenerate case of Ohm's law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kircchoff's voltage rule is still satisfied.  The circuit's wires actually have a small resistance associated with them, and the battery has an internal resistance associated with it.  The assumption is usually (and correctly) made that the internal battery resistance and the resistance in the wires can be ignored (i.e., assumed to be zero), because the external resistance in the circuit is so much greater than other circuit resistances.  When you short the battery, current in the circuit will rise substantially, but it will still be limited by V=IR.

Comment: What if it was an ideal battery and wire?

Comment: @Goldname, an ideal battery and ideal wire connected together yield a contradiction, e.g., 9V = 0V.  The same problem arises if two ideal voltage sources, of different voltages, are parallel connected (or if two ideal current sources, of different currents, are series connected).  In other words, there are certain connections of *ideal* circuit elements that aren't valid.

Comment: @Goldname Physics can provide answers to physical situations.  But it has nothing to say about impossible situations.

Comment: An 'ideal' battery is an irresistible force.   A perfect short circuit is an immovable object.  Those describe a contradiction in terms, not a physical situation.   In real life, shorting a battery makes it explode.